# Display results from array Javascript

Tags: javascript

I need som help with my code. Sorry for the long list. I'm student and new at JS :)

1. The result shows Name: Adress: Time: etc.

I only want to show the information after the "":

2. If I only want to show parts of the array (price, time etc). How do I do?
3. I want the button to be a link.

```js
let data = [{

        "name": "Sax & Fön",
        "adress": "Rådmansgatan 46",
        "zip": "113 57 Stockholm",
        "time": "12",
        "tel": "08-522 389 20",
        "site": "www.salongweb.se",
        "rating": "(32)",
        "price": "320 kr",
        "timeEst": "30 min",
        "open": "Öppet till 19.00 idag",
        "desc": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris"
    },

    {
        "name": "Hårizont",
        "adress": "Rådmansgatan 46",
        "zip": "113 57 Stockholm",
        "time": "12",
        "tel": "08-522 389 20",
        "site": "www.salongweb.se",
        "rating": "(32)",
        "price": "320 kr",
        "timeEst": "30 min",
        "open": "Öppet till 19.00 idag",
        "desc": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris"

    }
];


let page2 = (hairdresser) => {
    let singleView = "<div>";
    for (prop in hairdresser) {
        if (hairdresser.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
            singleView += `<p>${prop} : ${hairdresser[prop]}</p>`;
        }
    }
    singleView += "</div>"
    document.body.innerHTML = singleView;
}

let handleData = (hairdressers) => {
    let out = "<table>";
    hairdressers.forEach((hairdresser, index) => {
        out += "<tr>";
        for (let prop in hairdresser) {
            if (hairdresser.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
                let isName = prop === "name";
                out += `<td>
        ${isName ? `<button onclick='page2(${JSON.stringify(hairdresser)})'}>` : ""}  
          ${prop}${hairdresser[prop]}
        ${isName ? '</button>' : ""}
        </td>`;
            }
        }
        out += "</tr>";
    })
    out += "</table>";

    document.body.innerHTML = out;

}

handleData(data);
```

```html
<html>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1 . The result shows Name: Adress: Time: etc.

I fixed it by removing ${prop} in the handleData function (this made it print the prop's name).

> 2 . If I only want to show parts of the array (price, time etc). How do I
>   do?

Instead of looping through all properties of your object, like you do with your for...in loop you can declare an array of properties you want to print and loop through it to only print these properties :

```
const printableProps = ["name", "price", "adress"];
printableProps.forEach(prop => {
    if (hairdresser.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
        singleView += `<p>${prop} : ${hairdresser[prop]}</p>`;
    }
});
```

> 3 . I want the button to be a link.

You can replace the `<button>` tag by a `<a>` there :

```
${isName ? `<a href="#" onclick='page2(${JSON.stringify(hairdresser)})'}>` : ""}  
          ${prop}${hairdresser[prop]}
        ${isName ? '</a>' : ""}
```

```js
let data = [{
        "name": "Sax & Fön",
        "adress": "Rådmansgatan 46",
        "zip": "113 57 Stockholm",
        "time": "12",
        "tel": "08-522 389 20",
        "site": "www.salongweb.se",
        "rating": "(32)",
        "price": "320 kr",
        "timeEst": "30 min",
        "open": "Öppet till 19.00 idag",
        "desc": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris"
    },
    {
        "name": "Hårizont",
        "adress": "Rådmansgatan 46",
        "zip": "113 57 Stockholm",
        "time": "12",
        "tel": "08-522 389 20",
        "site": "www.salongweb.se",
        "rating": "(32)",
        "price": "320 kr",
        "timeEst": "30 min",
        "open": "Öppet till 19.00 idag",
        "desc": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris"
    }
];

let page2 = (hairdresser) => {
    let singleView = "<div>";

    for (prop in hairdresser) {
        if (hairdresser.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
            singleView += `<p>${prop} : ${hairdresser[prop]}</p>`;
        }
    }

    singleView += "</div>"
    document.body.innerHTML = singleView;
}

let handleData = (hairdressers) => {
    let out = "<table>";
    hairdressers.forEach((hairdresser, index) => {
        out += "<tr>";

        const printableProps = ["name", "price", "adress"];
        printableProps.forEach(prop => {
            if (hairdresser.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
                let isName = prop === "name";
                out += `<td>
        ${isName ? `<a href="#" onclick='page2(${JSON.stringify(hairdresser)})'}>` : ""}  
          ${hairdresser[prop]}
        ${isName ? '</a>' : ""}
        </td>`;
            }
        });
        out += "</tr>";
    })
    out += "</table>";

    document.body.innerHTML = out;
}

handleData(data);
```

```html
<html>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's the part handledata I want to show ["name", "price", "adress"];

Comment: @Erika No problem. Make sure to accept this answer if your problem is solved :)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understood correctly but You may call that specific part using the structure you have created:

for example:

```
data[0].price
```

would give you '320kr' which is the value in the first set of data